# Is there a let / flet / labels like concept for binding closures to avoid funcall?

Tags: closures, common-lisp, function-call

Whilst going over [let over lambda](http://letoverlambda.com) I happened across

```
(defmacro! dlambda (&rest ds)
  `(lambda (&rest ,g!args)
     (case (car ,g!args)
       ,@(mapcar
           (lambda (d)
             `(,(if (eq t (car d))
                  t
                  (list (car d)))
               (apply (lambda ,@(cdr d))
                      ,(if (eq t (car d))
                         g!args
                         `(cdr ,g!args)))))
           ds))))
```

Which they subsequently invoke like so:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'count-test)
    (let ((count 0))
      (dlambda
        (:inc () (incf count))
        (:dec () (decf count)))))
```

Is there a construct like flet / labels / let that I can bind the resulting closure to, so as to avoid using funcall or the setf symbol-function in a global manner? So I can do something like:

```
(with-closures ((counter (let ((count 0))
                          (dlambda
                           (:inc () (incf count))
                           (:dec () (decf count))))))
              (counter :incf))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a macro:

```
(defmacro as-functions ((&rest names) &body body)
  (assert (every #'symbolp names) () "Names must be symbols")
  (let ((args (copy-symbol :args)))
    `(flet
         ,(mapcar (lambda (n) `(,n (&rest ,args) (apply ,n ,args))) names)
       ,@body)))
```

For each symbol `s` in `names`, bind this symbol in the *function namespace* to the function currently bound by this symbol in the *variable namespace*. This can shadow any functions already named `s` in current lexical scope,  but since it is done explicitly, the programmer shouldn't be caught by surprise.
For example:

```
(let ((a (lambda (u) (+ 3 u)))
      (b (lambda (u) (* 2 u))))
  (as-functions (a b)
    (a (b 3))))
```

... macroexpands as:

```
(LET ((A (LAMBDA (U) (+ 3 U))) (B (LAMBDA (U) (* 2 U))))
  (FLET ((A (&REST #:ARGS)
           (APPLY A #:ARGS))
         (B (&REST #:ARGS)
           (APPLY B #:ARGS)))
    (A (B 3))))
```

... and evaluates to 9.

Contrary to a binding construct, this can be used with function arguments:

```
(defun compose (f g)
  (as-functions (f g)
    (lambda (x) (f (g x)))))
```

#### Provide bindings too

Based from  a comment from jkiiski, here is a modified version which accepts `(name fun)` bindings in addition to single symbols. This looks like `FLET`, except that functions can be computed at runtime.

```
(defmacro as-functions ((&rest names) &body body)
  (let ((args (copy-symbol :args)))
    `(flet
         ,(mapcar
           (lambda (name)
             (etypecase name
               (symbol `(,name (&rest ,args) (apply ,name ,args)))
               (cons (destructuring-bind (name fun) name
                       `(,name (&rest ,args) (apply ,fun ,args))))))
           names)
       ,@body)))
```

And so:

```
(defun thing (f g h)
  (as-functions (f (k (compose g h)))
    (f (k 3))))
```

---

<sub>Edit: I remembered having read such a macro previously, using `MACROLET`: see [this reply](http://www.xach.com/naggum/articles/3225069211869395@naggum.net.html) from Erik Naggum in comp.lang.lisp's *Re: Why is Scheme not a Lisp?*</sub>

Comment: If we think a moment about efficiency, consing rest arglists, applying functions on list arguments and added non-inlined functions may need more work for 'production' code. See also dynamic-extent declarations...